# Adjust variance of zero value in R

Tags: r, zero, variance

I am not sure if I will manage to ask right but I have a continuous time series data sets, that have a DAILY zero value variance and it is necessary to actually find a way managing it.
Exaple:
In the pictures I attached the data set and the data visualisation [Data visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBb8t.png)[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svp6m.png).
[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUROO.png)
There you can see that the values are up to the zero and varies a lot.

Thanks for any help

How can I adjust such data variation to zero values by each day (as the variation differs daily).

Comment: `it is necessary to actually find a way managing it` why? how? What is your research question? Why do you need this?

Comment: I need to find difference between two groups (Case and control). The data represents greenhouse gasses measurements, that needs to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: Then compute the differences, what is the issue? Why do you think the data needs to be changed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.